# Google Login in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to use Google Apis for login in Windows Phone 8.1.
I have this method:

```
public async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var Credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new Uri("ms-appx:///Shared/Jsons/client_secrets.json"),
            new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin},
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Credential: {Credential}");
        var loginSuccess = await NetworkManager.LoginWithGoogle(Credential.Token.AccessToken);

        return loginSuccess;      
    }
```

Everything after GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() is not executed. 
Also if i try to debug i put breakpoint on that instruction and when i go further i see the app going out of that method, without execute all the other instructions.
I have no exception and so i don't know why.

Some hint?